# my recursive function keeps going even after reaching the base case

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, return

this is a c++ recursive function, it's supposed to find a path in a linked list. I can't make it finish after reaching the base case. It just keeps going even after the return;

```
void navigateGraph(ListNode *currentNode, ListNode *destinationNode, string currentPath) {
// Base case
if (currentNode == destinationNode) {
    cout << "Ending reached!" << endl;
    cout << "Path taken: " << currentPath << destinationNode->name << endl;
    return;
}

currentNode->visited = 1;

if (currentNode->up != nullptr && currentNode->up->visited == 0) {
    cout << "Moving upward to " << currentNode->up->name << endl;
    navigateGraph(currentNode->up, destinationNode, currentPath + currentNode->name + " ");
}

if (currentNode->left != nullptr && currentNode->left->visited == 0) {
    cout << "Moving left to " << currentNode->left->name << endl;
    navigateGraph(currentNode->left, destinationNode, currentPath + currentNode->name + " ");
}

if (currentNode->down != nullptr && currentNode->down->visited == 0) {
    cout << "Moving downward to " << currentNode->down->name << endl;
    navigateGraph(currentNode->down, destinationNode, currentPath + currentNode->name + " ");
}

if (currentNode->right != nullptr && currentNode->right->visited == 0) {
    cout << "Moving right to " << currentNode->right->name << endl;
    navigateGraph(currentNode->right, destinationNode, currentPath + currentNode->name + " ");
}

if (currentNode->visited == 1) {
    cout << "Current path from " << currentNode->name << " ends" << endl;
}
```

}

How can I make the recursion stop after the base case.

Comment: What happens if multiple conditions happens to be true? Maybe you should use `else if` instead of plain `if`?

Comment: Also, with `current->visited = 1;` the condition `if (current->visited == 1)` will always be true.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude already tried that, does the same thing:(

Comment: I'd guess your function needs to return `true` when it reaches the base case, then if the calling function receives `true` as the result it should return immediately rather than recursing further

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about the if current->visited =1, I forgot to delete the else before posting, I just edited it I'm sorry

Comment: @AlanBirtles already tried that, but the recursion finishes the path no matter what.

Comment: Try following the code execution in your mind. When entering the call for "F", you go up to "C" and reaches the end, so the call for "C" ends and returns to the call for "F", but at that point the function continues and look for going left, down and right. Going down to "I" is possible and since the function has no knowledge that the end was found, it continues as it should if the end was not already found. Consider the suggestion of @AlanBirtles. If it did not work, you did not implement it correctly.

Comment: I keep thinking about what my professor told me, I think I already got it I'm just not seeing something. I also just realized that the instructions mention that the path is going to be in REVERSE because of the BASE CASE, and I'm also realizing that the last lines of my output are kind of the path in reverse (excluding the I)

Comment: @nielsen thank you, I'll try something with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to resolve the problem you highlight, is to make the recursive function *return* something: an indication whether the end node was found (and output) or not. So this could be a boolean. Then at each place where you make the recursive call, you should check its return value. If it indicates that the path was already found, then return immediately, again indicating success. Otherwise have the code continue like you have it now so that other possibilities can be explored.

Here is a spoiler in case you cannot make it work:

> `bool recursiveFunction(ListNode *current, ListNode *ending, string path) {
>      //base case
>      if (current == ending) {
>          cout << "Destination reached!" << endl;
>          cout << "Path was: " << path << ending->name << endl;
>                  //delete current; didn't work either
>          return true; // Indicate success
>      }
>      current->visited = 1;
>      if (current->up != nullptr && current->up->visited == 0) {
>          cout << "Going up to " << current->up->name << endl;
>          if (recursiveFunction(current->up, ending, path + current->name + " ")) return true;
>      }
>
>      if (current->left != nullptr && current->left->visited == 0) {
>          cout << "Going left to " << current->left->name << endl;
>          if (recursiveFunction(current->left, ending, path + current->name + " ")) return true;
>      }
>
>      if (current->down != nullptr && current->down->visited == 0) {
>          cout << "Going down to " << current->down->name << endl;
>          if (recursiveFunction(current->down, ending, path + current->name + " ")) return true;
>      }
>
>      if (current->right != nullptr && current->right->visited == 0) {
>          cout << "Going right to " << current->right->name << endl;
>          if (recursiveFunction(current->right, ending, path + current->name + " ")) return true;
>      }
>      if (current->visited == 1) {
>          cout << current->name << " ends" << endl;
>      }
>      return false;
>  }`

However, there is actually a more elegant algorithm (in my humble opinion), where you don't have to pass `path` as argument: It is then only *after* having found the end node that you start to identify nodes as being on the path, which should happen while unwinding from recursion.

Unrelated, but I would try to avoid the code repetition you have for dealing with the four directions. Use a helper function for the common code.

Again a spoiler for that idea:

> `bool recursiveFunction(ListNode *current, ListNode *ending);
>
>  // Helper function to avoid code repetition
>  bool visitNeighbor(ListNode *neighbor, string direction, ListNode *ending) {
>      if (neighbor && !neighbor->visited) {
>          cout << "Going " << direction << " to " << neighbor->name << endl;
>          return recursiveFunction(neighbor, ending);
>      }
>      return false;
>  }
>
>  bool recursiveFunction(ListNode *current, ListNode *ending) {
>      //base case
>      if (current == ending) {
>          // Output the success message. The actual nodes on the path will follow later...
>          cout << "Destination reached, path was:";
>      }
>      current->visited = 1;
>      bool found = current == ending ||
>                   visitNeighbor(current->up,    "up",    ending) ||
>                   visitNeighbor(current->left,  "left",  ending) ||
>                   visitNeighbor(current->down,  "down",  ending) ||
>                   visitNeighbor(current->right, "right", ending);
>      if (found) {
>          // Output the node on the path (in reverse order)
>          cout << " " << current->name;
>          return true; // ... and indicate success
>      }
>      cout << current->name << " ends" << endl;
>      return false;
>  }`

Comment: you solution worked fine, thank you very much. Here when you mentioned **This is actually a more elegant algorithm (in my humble opinion), [...] ** my professor told me he wanted this approach, but I keep getting the "(name) ends" message, I can't get it to display just the name of the node at the end of the program. If you could help me I would appreciate it a lot, If not, I completely understand. Again, Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Sure I want to help with that, but I don't understand what you mean with "I keep getting..." and "I can't get it to display just the name of the node at the end of the program". Do you mean you don't need to output the nodes as you discover them *during* the recursive execution, and only need to output them once the recursive function has completed? What about the "going down" messages, and "Destination reached"... etc. Do you need them or not?

Comment: OK, I added messages like "H ends" to the second code snippet. Is it like that you need it?

Comment: Yess! Thank you so much, do you have cash app?

Comment: Look at my profile page ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to delete the post? since this is homework

Comment: I don't think that is possible at this stage.  The moment you post on Stack Overflow you agree to sharing to the public. You can however edit your question slightly, but be aware that it is not appreciated if you delete essential stuff from the question (like your code attempt and the actual question), as those are necessary ingredients for a question on Stack Overflow, and such tampering will be reverted by reviewers. Also, changes should not invalidate answers. But you can change variable names, use different example input, ...etc.

Comment: I can also hide the solution code I provided, in a way that you must first click on a blank space before it appears. Tell me if you prefer that.

Comment: Yes please, I would appreciate that.

Comment: Ok done. Good like that?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!